# Git wants a password even though its setup with key authentication

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

I've got an issue using git. When I'm trying to access a repository, git will automatically prompt for a password, even though auth via password is disabled on the gitserver.

My ssh config is as follows (hostname/repository are anonymized):

```
host gitserver
  user gitolite
  hostname server.example.com
  identityfile ~/.ssh/gitolite
```

When i try to clone the repo however its fails, due to a password request:

```
git clone gitolite@server.example.com:repository
Cloning into 'repository'...
gitolite@server.example.com's password:
```

The ~/.ssh folder, as well as its content are set up with permissions 700 as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication) (one of the many things i tried).

Anyone got a solution to this?

**Edit:**

Other attempts to clone failed exactly the same way

```
git clone gitserver:repository
Cloning into 'repository'...
gitolite@server.example.com's password:
```

**Edit2:**

```
ssh -Tv gitserver
```

results in the following output:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/username/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/username/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for gitserver
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server.example.com [1.2.3.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/gitolite type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/gitolite-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 00:df:a5:58:af:45:be:eb:62:65:07:5d:85:20:7c:98
debug1: Host 'server.example.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/username/.ssh/gitolite
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/username/.ssh/gitolite
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
gitolite@server.example.com's password:
```

Comment: I'm confused because you have 'user git' in the config file, and are also passing a different user to git clone (gitolite@). Maybe that's why it doesn't use the config.

Comment: It also looks like you're using different hostnames (`server.example.com` on the command line, but `gitserver` in the config).

Comment: @RemcoGerlich  that was a typo in the question sry, i corrected that one

Comment: @robertklep gitserver is just a synonym, it doesnt change anything if i use the same name as for hostname

Comment: Key is rejected. You probably did not set the authentication properly.

Comment: @Jakuje where do you actually see the reject? The only thing I see is the missing response.

Comment: It was offered and not accepted = rejected.

Comment: I agree. ssh should *not* ask for password. If it does, it means the public key is not found on the server side, on `~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the reason for the password prompts.

Apparently one of the earlier commands for gitolite which was supposed to increase supported file sizes in git could not be run, which caused following key updates for gitolite to be stuck in a queue.

Therefore `~/.ssh/known_hosts` was never updated by gitolite on server-side, resulting in the decline of the key.

Comment: Nice feedback. +1. Thank you for letting all of us know what was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want  to use the private key used by gitolite, the ssh url must be:

```
git clone gitserver:repository
```

That will use the `~/.ssh/gitolite` private key, identifying you as git on the gitolite server.

Comment: Unfortunately i tried this before as well, resulting in exactly the same situation.

Comment: Then try `ssh -Tv gitserver`: does that work? As long as it does not work, no gitolite operation will be possible. Note that using this particular key is useful for cloning gitolite-admin. It should not be use to clone any git Repo managed by Gitolilte.

Comment: `gitolite@server.example.com:repository` is not the same as `gitserver:repository`: the first one relies on the default `id_rsa(.pub)` ssh keys. The second one uses the gitolite private key.

Comment: as i said in an earlier post, unfortunately both attempts result in the same situation

Comment: The ssh command you posted seemed to work as i cant see any errors in the debug output generated

Comment: @Taredon I agree. I am just explaining the difference between both attempts. First, let's make sure ssh is working. See http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#ssh

Comment: Can you clone the gitolite-admin repo?

Comment: @Taredon looks like a simple ssh is not working then. Redo the gitolite setup, and make sure ssh is working *before* trying to clone anything. http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html

Comment: Trying to clone the gitolite-admin repo results in the same situation

Comment: @Taredon Exactly: solve ssh first, then deal with gitolite repos.

Comment: The strange thing about this is that my pubkey was added the same way to gitolite like any other, which unlike mine do actually work. I already double checked it's the correct key.

Comment: @Taredon `gitserver` would use the gitolite key, not your own key though.

Comment: I just named the keys gitolite/gitolite.pub on my local machine, these are still the keys i created and the ones im currently using

Comment: At this point, it is best to redo the gitolite setup and check the pre-requisite: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html